# Asp.net losing session on post back on some pages in chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, session

I am trying to deploy a Vb.net Asp.net Web forms application, but having problems.

We have a slightly bizarre problem where we seem to be losing session on some aspx pages in chrome on post back (not all).

It seems perfectly fine in internet Explorer and Firefox.

This only happens when deployed to IIS 6, and not when debugging locally.

It is using HTTPS.

Does anybody have any ideas or suggestions why might be or where to focus the investigation?

No JavaScript errors are found.
No errors are happening in codebehinds.

Thanks for any help!

---

Update 1:
Thanks for comments. We have the same ASP.NET_SessionId in the cookies on all pages - this never changes... 1. Enter first page, fill out form, session variables are added 2. Enter the second page we have the session variables, these are checked on the page_load event. 3. Fill out form on the second page and submit, we hit the page_load event, once again we check that the session variables are present, but this time they are missing. ...There isn't anywhere in the code where we clear these session variables. This is a web application project.

I think we are using forms authentication, it is set to allow anonymous as this will be a public application This is only happening in Chrome, and only happening when deployed to IIS - it isn't happening when debugging locally with the Visual Studio 2010 test web server. Could there be some obscure environmental problem? It is very frustrating! :/ I'm not currently at work so I will need to double check some of the other details, this is code we have recently inherited and the original authors are not with us. Thanks very much for all your help! I really appreciate this.

Update 2:
We are losing session variables somewhere between the SaveStateComplete event on the page and the postback.

- Page_Load - QuoteCarousel.aspx - **is postback = False** Session Id: yu2afsxpafu0qmzbkxqp1dd4. **items in session: 23**
- Page_SaveStateComplete QuoteCarousel.aspx Session Id: yu2afsxpafu0qmzbkxqp1dd4. **items in session: 32**
- Page_PreInit QuoteCarousel.aspx Session Id: yu2afsxpafu0qmzbkxqp1dd4. **items in session: 7**
- Page_Init QuoteCarousel.aspx Session Id: yu2afsxpafu0qmzbkxqp1dd4. **items in session: 8**
- Page_InitComplete QuoteCarousel.aspx Session Id: yu2afsxpafu0qmzbkxqp1dd4. **items in session: 8**
- Page_Load - QuoteCarousel.aspx - **is postback = True** Session Id: yu2afsxpafu0qmzbkxqp1dd4. **items in session: 8**

Comment: most likely there is a cookie called `ASP.NET_SessionId` tell us if its value changed at any point during the post backs or if the cookie is removed

Comment: additionally tell us if your session is `in proc` or `state server` and what is your session timeout.

Comment: what type of project is deployed `web application project` or `web site project`?

Comment: What is the `postback` doing? Show us the codebehind of your postback.

Comment: How do you determined that session is lost? What is the behavior that changes in chrome over IE for example?

Comment: What type of authentication are you using: windows or forms?

Comment: Is your application pool set for webgarden? If it is, and you are using in process session this would be a problem.

Comment: Post your javascript code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application was in a physical folder in the website.
I changed this to a virtual folder and it fixed the problem. I am still not clear as to the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This may help some people.  I had the exact same problem.  Worked in Firefox, worked in IE.  Lost session in Chrome.  Basically, I was setting up and binding a gridview and then setting a session variable.  When a postback would be triggered, by the time the code ran in the RowCommand event, the session variables were all lost.

I'm not exactly sure why this works, but I had these values in  in the web.config (think they got added automatically when I added some MVC elements to my website):

```
<!--
    <add key="PageInspector:ServerCodeMappingSupport" value="Disabled" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
-->
```

When I commented these values out, everything started working in Chrome.  Since I wasn't actually using the MVC references that I added, I am good with this solution, but I'm not sure why it worked.